How can I improve these downvoted questions?
I see I got serial downvoted:

Links to the questions:

What's the max latency for OpenAI models accessed via Azure with provisioned throughput units? (mirror, since it got removed by Roomba due to the downvote)
What's the difference between "Tokens per Minute Rate Limit (thousands)" and "Rate limit (Tokens per minute)" in Azure OpenAI?

Of course, the questions were chosen to trigger Roomba. Anyway, how can I improve these questions?

I mean.. what's the harm in an old post no one seemed to care about (until you invited people from meta to upvote it) going away (particularly one that seems to have just been a temporary bug in azure that has long been fixed apparently?)

@KevinB the max latency for OpenAI models accessed via Azure with provisioned throughput unitsthroughput units is of high interest to many people using genAI with azure. The other post is indeed less important now but I prefer to know what happened.
